# How to match Nullable Date parameter in f#

Tags: f#, nullable

Learning F#, can't find the answer to this... I'd like to handle case where a Nullable parameter (DateTime? in the original c#) is null, but I get the error "Nullable does not have null as a proper value". What is the correct way to do this?

```
let addIfNotNull(ht:Hashtable, key:string, value:Nullable<DateTime>) = 
        match value with 
        | null -> ()
        | _ -> ht.Add(key,value)
        ht
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/nullable-operators:

> The actual value can be obtained from a `System.Nullable<'T>` object by using the `Value` property, and you can determine if a `System.Nullable<'T>` object has a value by calling the `HasValue` method.

So instead of the `match` you do

```
if value.HasValue then ht.Add(key, value.Value)
```

You could use

```
match Option.ofNullable value with ...
```

or declare some active patterns to help.

Comment: `Option.ofNullable` is actually there.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: I had to work out that the Option.ofNullable version would match against None instead of null, both versions (ofNullable, compare value property) work perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

While @AlexeyRomanov's answer is perfectly valid, if you really want to match over a `Nullable` value, you can define an Active Pattern like so:

```
let (|Null|Value|) (x : _ Nullable) =
    if x.HasValue then Value x.Value else Null
```

And then use it in your function:

```
let addIfNotNull (ht : Hashtable) (key : string)
                 (value : Nullable<DateTime>) =
    match value with
    | Null -> ()
    | Value dt -> ht.Add (key, dt)
    ht
```

I took the liberty to change your function's signature so it takes curried parameters; unless you have specific requirements, curried parameters are usually preferred over tupled parameters.